# Android: How to give a TextView a focusable style after adding focusable=true and focusableInTouchMode=true?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, textview, android-styles, android

I have simple TextView that does a function when Touched/Focused,

I've set it focusable as follows:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/post_interests"
  style="@style/InterestsEditText"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Select Interest(s)"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</TextView>
```

and added this style to it:

```
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView" name="InterestsEditText">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>       
</style>
```

What I need now is to make it look like an **Edit Text** when it gains focus as its current look doesn't change when it gets focus. **but the focus event is triggered.**

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an EditText and give it a background to get the desired look? Is there any specific functionality of a TextView that you are aiming to use?